# Randomizing structure with typedefs

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to randomize a structure which has typedefs, but it is not getting randomized. How can I achieve that?

```
typedef enum bit[1:0]{A=0, B=1,E=2,F=3}dl_pkt_type;
typedef enum bit[2:0]{G=4,H=5,C=6, D=7}tl_pkt_type;
  
  typedef struct {
    dl_pkt_type dl_pkt;
    tl_pkt_type tl_pkt;
  } pkt_struct;
    
class packet;

 rand pkt_struct p;
 rand dl_pkt_type dl;
 rand tl_pkt_type tl;
  //pre randomization function
  function void pre_randomize();
    $display("Inside pre_randomize");
  endfunction
  
  //post randomization function
  function void post_randomize();
    $display("Inside post_randomize");
    $display("dl: %0s   tl: %0s",p.dl_pkt,p.tl_pkt);
    $display("dl: %0s   tl: %0s",dl,tl);
  endfunction
endclass

module rand_methods;
  initial begin
    packet pkt;
    pkt = new();
    pkt.randomize;
  end
endmodule
```

This is the output that I am getting:

```
Inside pre_randomize
Inside post_randomize
p.dl_pkt: A   p.tl_pkt: 
dl: B   tl: G
```

I am expecting `p.dl_pkt` and `p.tl_pkt` to be randomized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the keyword `rand` to your struct, too:

```
  typedef struct {
    rand dl_pkt_type dl_pkt;
    rand tl_pkt_type tl_pkt;
  } pkt_struct;
```

---

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/BsLJ

```
typedef enum bit[1:0]{A=0, B=1,E=2,F=3}dl_pkt_type;
typedef enum bit[2:0]{G=4,H=5,C=6, D=7}tl_pkt_type;
  
  typedef struct {
    rand dl_pkt_type dl_pkt;
    rand tl_pkt_type tl_pkt;
  } pkt_struct;
    
class packet;

 rand pkt_struct p;
 rand dl_pkt_type dl;
 rand tl_pkt_type tl;
  //pre randomization function
  function void pre_randomize();
    $display("Inside pre_randomize");
  endfunction
  
  //post randomization function
  function void post_randomize();
    $display("Inside post_randomize");
    $display("dl: %0s   tl: %0s",p.dl_pkt.name,p.tl_pkt.name);
    $display("dl: %0s   tl: %0s",dl.name,tl.name);
  endfunction
endclass

module rand_methods;
  initial begin
    packet pkt;
    pkt = new();
    pkt.randomize;
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this answer while looking for a solution for the same problem. The mistake I did was to use an `unpacked` struct. Once I modified my struct to `packed`, the randomization started working.

You can declare `pkt_struct` as packed:

```
typedef struct packed {
    dl_pkt_type dl_pkt;
    tl_pkt_type tl_pkt;
} pkt_struct;
```

And then declare a variable of type `pkt_struct` inside the class, class without having to modify the structs members:

```
class packet;
    rand pkt_struct p;
    ...
endclass
```